# QGIS - Is it possible to bypass an inaccurate WMS bounding box provided by server metadata?

Tags: qgis, wms, qgis-3

In QGIS,
is there a way to bypass / ignore an inaccurate WMS bounding box provided by server metadata?

Indeed, for a specific WMS layer I am using, the bounding box provided by server metadata does not match the underlying data's extent (some data exist out of the "official" bounding box delivered by metadata request). Thus, I would like to prevent QGIS from using the inaccurate metadata so that I can see all of the data.

Comment: Please decide which of QGIS and ArcGIS Desktop you wish to ask about in this particular question.

Comment: The `EX_GeographicBoundingBox` is only intended as a hint to the total extent of the data available in the service / or layer.  A WMS GetMap request can be made with any bounding box.

Comment: Indeed, a WMS GetMap _can_ be made with any bounding box, thing is QGIS trust the layer's `EX_GeographicBoundingBox` metadata as factual and seems not to query GetMap requests out of this inaccurate extent.

Comment: seems not?  Perhaps the service has some restriction that doesn't allow such a  query to render output, but it's not a restriction of QGIS.  For example here's a GetMap request generated by QGIS http://ogc2.bgs.ac.uk/cgi-bin/UGA_ARGID/ows?language=eng&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&BBOX=-1263120,-572489,1393160,486111&CRS=EPSG:32635&WIDTH=112&HEIGHT=45&LAYERS=DAD_ITEMS&STYLES=&FORMAT=image/png&DPI=96&MAP_RESOLUTION=96&FORMAT_OPTIONS=dpi:96&TRANSPARENT=TRUE that's way outside the bounding box of the layer specified in the metadata

Comment: Weird... (my QGIS version is 3.2.2-Bonn). It cannot be a service restriction since a manual WMS request (= with a hard-coded bbox out of metadata extent) give some data but I have no mean in QGIS to see this data (in QGIS I only see data in the metadata extent).

Comment: @nmtoken by the way : the metadata of your layer is `<BoundingBox CRS="EPSG:32635" minx="-1.26312e+06" miny="-572489" maxx="1.39316e+06" maxy="486111" />` which is precisely the bbox QGIS requested for you in EPSG:32635